# How to attach custom taxonomy to a post in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

A have a lot of posts with custom post types in the database. In the same time the theme created the taxonomy institution:

```
function my_taxonomies_institutions() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Category', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        // and tothers
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'hierarchical'       => true,
        'show_admin_column'  => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'slug' => 'institutions' ),
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'institutions', 'institution', $args ); 
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_taxonomies_institutions', 0 );
```

OK, there's a menu item Instituitions in admin zone, and a bit of Categories there, for example - Sections. Now in order to animate the theme that constructed for this taxonomy I need to go through all posts and to attach the Instituitions term to the post depending of it's post_type.

```
print term_exists('sections'); // 7
```

I tried the following

```
$ret = wp_set_post_terms($pid, 7, 'institution');
$ret = wp_set_post_terms($pid, 'sections', 'institution');
```

but result was

> WP_Error Object ( [errors] => Array ( [invalid_taxonomy] => Array ( [0] => Неверная таксономия. ) ) [error_data] => Array ( ) )

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: in your code you are creating a ustom post not a taxnomy, take a look to this thread https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84921/how-do-i-query-a-custom-post-type-with-a-custom-taxonomy

Comment: Sorry, I posted another piece of code. Corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You registered taxonomy with name `institutions` but using `institution` by mistake, hence te error `[invalid_taxonomy]`. It should be like this

```
$ret = wp_set_post_terms($pid, array(7,), 'institutions');
$ret = wp_set_post_terms($pid, array('sections',), 'institutions');
```

To assign this term "sections" with `term_id = 7` to all posts of type `institution`, do something like

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
  'post_type' => 'institution',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1
));

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
   wp_set_post_terms( $post->ID, array(7,), 'institutions');
   // OR 
   // wp_set_post_terms( $post->ID, array ('sections',), 'institutions');
}
```

I hope this will work.
Please have a look at [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_terms) codex page for further info.

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
$posts = get_posts([
  'post_type' => 'institution',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'numberposts' => -1
]);

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
   wp_set_post_terms( $post->ID; array( ), 'institutions');
}
```

also if you want to wp_set_post_terms by id, you should use `wp_set_post_terms( $post->ID; array( $id ))` instead of `wp_set_post_terms( $post->ID; $id)` take a look [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_terms)